# How to aggregate row responses of same user id into columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to group by user id, so that there is only one row per user. So that this:
 [image]

tranforms into this:

[image]

I've got the question titles as columns on the right that I need to put answer values in. So basically, for each user, I have to match the values from the "question_title" to the correct question column on the right, and then and then place the value from the respective "answers" column in there. 
To match the questions, i would only need to match the question number, i.e. the digits instead of the whole string.

I tried to use the transform function as shown below:

```
newdf1.groupby('question_title')['user_id'].transform('first').
```

I also tried to iterate row by row by using the apply function, but this creates a new column instead of matching the existing columns:

```
def rayyan(row):
    val = row['question_title']
    return val

newdf1.apply(rayyan, axis=1)
```

Could you please help? thanks.

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. Also [don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly what you looking for is:

```py
newdf1.groupby(['question_title','user_id'])['answer'].first().unstack('question_title')
```

But a data example that is copy- and pasteable would be really helpfull in the future.